# SharePoint Internet Explorer 7 Rendering issues

Tags: browser-compatibility

this is my first post here. I have tried to find something similar to my question, but I may have missed an appropriate answer. My apologies if I am asking the same question twice.

I have a page that adds scroll-bars when rendered in IE-7. See picture below:

Please excuse an external link, I have to earn more rep points before I can post an image:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/15/scrollbars2.png/

When rendered in different browsers the yellow highlighted areas are not scroll-bars. I am guessing this is a CSS issue. Any suggestions, experience, or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you referring to the scrollbars not showing in Chrome or other browsers besides Chrome?

Comment: Chrome, Firefox, and Safari all seem to render fine. It is only IE 7 (so far) that has rendering issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try removing any min-width from html, body and any custom containers that your markup has.

You can also try adding s4-nosetwidth to the  element in the Master Page.

In any case, can you please post part of your HTML and CSS code?

Comment: I removed min-width and added overflow: auto. That seemed to do the trick! Thanks for your help, it is greatly appreciated.